# How to make rule "templates"

Tags: antlr4

I have a grammar something like this:

```
start : topDef* EOF ;
topDef : topId '(' scopeDef* ')' ;
topId : UPPER_ID ;
scopeDef : scopeId '(' scopeDef* ')' ;
scopeId : LOWER_ID NUMBER? ;

UPPER_ID : [A-Z] [A-Za-z0-9_]* ;
LOWER_ID : [a-z] [A-Za-z0-9_]* ;
NUMBER : [0-9]+ ;
WS : [ \t\r\n]+ -> skip ;
```

As can be seen, `topDef` and `scopeDef` are the same except for the id subrule. Is there some way to wrap these into one definition? Maybe a way to template rules like

```
start : def<topId>* EOF ;
def<id> : id '(' def<scopeId>* ')' ;
topId : UPPER_ID ;
scopeId : LOWER_ID NUMBER? ;
```

Or maybe something like

```
scopeDef : topDef except(topId : LOWER_ID NUMBER?) ;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not without a predicate (which contains target specific code, Java in the example below):

```
start : def[true]* EOF ;

def[boolean isTopDef]
 : ( {$isTopDef}? topId | scopeId ) '(' def[false]* ')'
 ;

topId : UPPER_ID ;
scopeId : LOWER_ID NUMBER? ;
```

So the answer is yes, you can do it, but I wouldn't if I were you.

Comment: My grammar is already java specific, so that's not a problem. I tried to more closely simulate my template idea using a `Runnable` parameter and calling it with `def[this::topId]` and `def[this::scopeId]`, but it didn't work.